# Moving data from a distributed Q/A excel file into a separate master file

Tags: excel, vba

I have designed and created a simple excel file for my work which will be distributed across the organisation where the recipient can answer a number of questions by selecting from drop down lists or entering specific details as required. As it will be sent out across the organisation, there will be numerous people filling in the report individually so eventually there will be a large number of files which will need to be sent back to me and I will have to combine all the files together into one master sheet to analyse.

I know how to insert buttons and link simple code to it for small actions like moving tabs, etc but what I would like is for a recipient to fill in the data sheet and click a button at the bottom which will take their answers from the entry sheet and populate another 'master'sheet where I can simply analyse the result at data. This would mean that I wouldn't have to chase anyone about sending their data back to me as it would automatically populate another sheet once a developer button is clicked.

To simplify things, lets imagine that there are 5 questions with question 1 being in A1 to A5 and each drop down answer list cell being in cell b1 - b5. In cell C1, There is a developer button called 'Finish'. Is it possible to have the data from this excel file transfer itself to another excel file so that Question 1 would appear in cell a1 with the resultant answer being in cell a2 and so forth (effectively flipped so can apply pivot table to results easier) after the finish button is clicked.

Many Thanks,

Graham

Answer (score 0):

The easier way will be to generate a csv file with username/id number as part of the file name with the relevant row information.  All the resultant .csv file kept in a folder then can be imported into another master excel using VBA/macro.

This will automate the entire process.

So say Cell A6 can be used to receive username/id etc , which can serve as a file name , as well as the part of the csv data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this.

```
Sub Copy_Every_Sheet_To_New_Workbook()
'Working in 97-2013
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DateString As String
    Dim FolderName As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'Copy every sheet from the workbook with this macro
    Set Sourcewb = ThisWorkbook

    'Create new folder to save the new files in
    DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
    FolderName = Sourcewb.Path & "\" & Sourcewb.Name & " " & DateString
    MkDir FolderName

    'Copy every visible sheet to a new workbook
    For Each sh In Sourcewb.Worksheets

        'If the sheet is visible then copy it to a new workbook
        If sh.Visible = -1 Then
            sh.Copy

            'Set Destwb to the new workbook
            Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

            'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
            With Destwb
                If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                    'You use Excel 97-2003
                    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
                Else
                    'You use Excel 2007-2013
                    If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
                        MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
                        GoTo GoToNextSheet
                    Else
                        Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
                        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                        Case 52:
                            If .HasVBProject Then
                                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                            Else
                                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                            End If
                        Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
                        Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
                        End Select
                    End If
                End If
            End With

            'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
            If Destwb.Sheets(1).ProtectContents = False Then
                With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
                    .Cells.Copy
                    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .Cells(1).Select
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If


            'Save the new workbook and close it
            With Destwb
                .SaveAs FolderName _
                      & "\" & Destwb.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr, _
                        FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
                .Close False
            End With

        End If
GoToNextSheet:
    Next sh

    MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

See this link for all details.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win007.htm